# Regex capture group within if statement in Java

Tags: java, regex, if-statement, capturing-group

I'm facing a stupid problem... I know how to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` objects to capture a group in Java.

However, I cannot find a way to use them with an `if` statement where each choice depends on a match (simple example to illustrate the question, in reality, it's more complicated) :

```
String input="A=B";
String output="";

if (input.matches("#.*")) {
    output="comment";
} else if (input.matches("A=(\\w+)")) {
    output="value of key A is ..."; //how to get the content of capturing group?
} else { 
    output="unknown";
}
```

Should I create a `Matcher` for each possible test?!

Comment: `} else if (input.matches("A=(\\w+)")) { output="value of key A is " + input.split("=")[1]; }`

Comment: If you really want to use regexep you should probably use 1 `Pattern` and 1 `Matcher` by `if` test. But if you know how to use it, I'm not sure to get the question ? Note that creating `Pattern` could be costly so avoid to create it at each call (https://www.baeldung.com/java-regex-pre-compile). By the way, maybe this is just a simple example to illustrate but in your simple case using regexep seems overkill.

Comment: `input.startsWith("#")` is a lot faster than input.matches("#.*").  Regular expressions are not the solution to every problem.

Comment: It *is* a simple example: the real problem is of course more complicated :)

Comment: @sbernard: the question was exactly that. In fact, I started using regex in Perl. And in Perl, it's very simple to code (no need to have as many objects as if statements). I found it strange to need as many Pattern/Matcher pairs as if statements and wanted to get advice thank you :) ! And yes, the real example is far more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should.

Here is the example.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Phone: (\\d{9})");
String str = "Phone: 123456789";
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    String g = m.group(1); // g should hold 123456789
}
```